# Merging multiple images (composite) with imagick php, and part of first image is getting erased

Tags: php, imagick

I'm dealing with PDF images.
I have a blank 'jig' image, which I will throw into my printer and I am trying to add job images onto it one at a time. With each image being in a different position, so as to not overlap.
The problem I am running into is that for some reason, the first job adds fine, but when I add the second job, the first job is partially erased. I've tried numerous composite algorithms, but if they work, they all have the same issue. Wondering if someone could point out my flaw in logic. I've attached some examples of the process at various stages.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param type $jig
 * @param type $point
 * @param string $original
 * @param string $additional
 */
public function addImageToImage($jig, $point, string $original, string $additional, string $jobBase)
{
    $preview = new Imagick();
    $preview->setResolution(300, 300);
    $preview->readImage($original);
    $jobImage = new Imagick();
    $jobImage->setResolution(300, 300);
    $jobImage->readImage($additional);
    $x = $this->mmToPx($jig["points"][$point][JigPoints::XCO] + $jig['products'][$jobBase][JigProducts::X_OFF]);
    $y = $this->mmToPx($jig["points"][$point][JigPoints::YCO] + $jig['products'][$jobBase][JigProducts::Y_OFF]);
    $preview->setImageBackgroundColor($jobImage->getImageBackgroundColor());
    $preview->setImageAlphaChannel($jobImage->getImageAlphaChannel());
    $preview->setImageType($jobImage->getImageType());
    $preview->compositeImage($jobImage,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DISSOLVE,$x,$y,$jobImage->getImageAlphaChannel());
    $preview->flattenImages();
    $preview->writeImage($original);
    $jobImage->destroy();
    $preview->destroy();
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for my issue.

Apparently if you create a new image in imagick, and then load your image, it behaves quite differently than if you create a new image FROM an existing image.
I'm not sure why part of the first image was always getting erased in my old method, but that doesn't happen with the following code.

```
/**
 * Adds a job image to a jig image.
 * 
 * @param [Jig]     $jig        - The Array containing the jig properties.
 * @param int       $point      - The position in the jib to place the job image.
 * @param sting     $original   - The PDF Jig image path.
 * @param string    $additional - The PDF Job image path.
 * @param int       $jobBase    - The base product code of the product used in this job.
 */
public function addImageToImage($jig, $point, string $original, string $additional, string $jobBase)
{
    //This condition has to be here, because of a glitch in Imagick, where 
    //improperly reads the preview image created earlier.
    if ($point === 0) {
        $preview = new Imagick($original);
        $preview->resampleImage(300, 300, 0, 1);
    } else {
        $preview = new Imagick();
        $preview->setResolution(300,300);
        $preview->readImage($original);
    }
    $jobImage = new Imagick();
    $jobImage->setResolution(300,300);
    $jobImage->readImage($additional);
    $x = $this->mmToPx($jig["points"][$point][JigPoints::XCO] + $jig['products'][$jobBase][JigProducts::X_OFF]);
    $y = $this->mmToPx($jig["points"][$point][JigPoints::YCO] + $jig['products'][$jobBase][JigProducts::Y_OFF]);
    $preview->compositeImage($jobImage,Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,$x,$y);
    $preview->writeImage($original);
    $jobImage->clear();
    $preview->clear();
}
```

Imagick appears to have a glitch when working with raster files and trying to load the image. If you setResolution(x,y), readImage() a PDF image, and then composite onto it, it works for the first composite, but if you setResolution, readImage() that same PDF image again, and composite onto it again, it screws up the image. To get around this, you need to create a new Imagick($source), resampleImage() to the correct resolution for the FIRST composite, and then setResolution() and loadImage() for every one after. This is offcourse assuming that you are working with a blank $preview image to start.